# Trouble importing Cytoscape and Dagre in Js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I'm trying to use Dagre with Cytoscape to visualize trees, but I'm having trouble when importing dagre and cytoscript in my javascript file. I keep getting an error "import declarations may appear only at a top level of a module".

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Document</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
   
        <div id="cy"></div>

        <script src="tree.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

My js file:

```
import cytoscape from 'cytoscape';
import dagre from 'cytoscape-dagre';

cytoscape.use( dagre );
```

When adding `type="module"` to my script tag in HTML I get a MIME type error (text/html).

I installed cytoscape-dagre via npm as per instructions on the Github repo: `npm install cytoscape-dagre`
https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre

Appreciate any help.

Comment: it seems like your problem is about importing a JS library.

Comment: @canbax Yes, I'm still verynew to JS. I'm currently having a script tag to load from CDN as a work-around. I tried all the same settings as examples on codepen and sandbox, but none seemed to worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues importing Cytoscape and Dagre in plain html/js as well, after trying many solutions, the only one that worked for me was to add:

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.23.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js" </script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-dagre@2.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
```

in my header. Then no need to import from `tree.js` like you're doing.